# reCAPTCHA not loading properly in XHTML document

Tags: xhtml, recaptcha, shtml

I am writing an SHTML CSS & JS document into an XML document which uses an XHTML parser.

When I try to load the captcha into it, it briefly shows up as a white box then disappears, never to be seen again inside the renderer.

I understand that this might be caused by the scripts being loaded in the wrong order but I don't have the luxury of the async defer keywords that are recommended by google simply because the parser won't accept them.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
class Token {

    constructor(tokenInstance) {
        this.props = tokenInstance;
        this.getStatus();
        this.setOnConfirm();
        this.setAdditionalProps();
    }

    setAdditionalProps() {
        this.props.claimed = false;
        this.props.claimTokensMessage = "Claim free DAI, DeFi & ETH tokens";
        this.props.claimedMessage = "You have already claimed DAI, DeFi & ETH tokens, stay posted for new freebies!";
        this.props.serverError = "Server Error, please try again later";
        this.props.success = "ETH, DeFi & DAI tokens will be sent to your address shortly!";
        this.props.fillCaptchaMessage = "Please click the captcha below to receive the tokens";
    }

    getBaseURL() {
        return "http://192.168.26.189:8080/api/" 
    }

    getStatus() {
        let suffix = "claimed?userAddress=" + this.props.ownerAddress;
        fetch(this.getBaseURL() + suffix).then((res) => {
            if(parseInt(res.status) === 200) {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.props.claimTokensMessage;
            } else if(parseInt(res.status) === 412) {
                this.props.claimed = true;
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.props.claimedMessage;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.props.serverError;
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = err;
            window.onConfirm = function() { window.close() };
        });
    }

    setOnConfirm() {
        window.onConfirm = () => {
            if(this.props.claimed) {
                window.close();
            } else {
                web3.personal.sign({ data: "To receive free tokens, you must reveal your public address to a smart contract. Is that ok?" }, (err, val) => {
                    if(err) { throw err; }
                    //user completes the request by filling the captcha
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.props.success;
                    document.getElementById("captcha").submit();
                    window.onConfirm = function () { window.close(); };
                });
            }
        };
    }

    render() {
        let suffix = "discover?userAddress=" + this.props.ownerAddress;
        return`
        <div class="ui container">
          <div class="ui segment">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAACVCAYAAAAdSLW3AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAABWWlUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnhtcAAAAAAAPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bWxuczp4PSJhZG9iZTpuczptZXRhLyIgeDp4bXB0az0iWE1QIENvcmUgNS40LjAiPgogICA8cmRmOlJERiB4bWxuczpyZGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvMDIvMjItcmRmLXN5bnRheC1ucyMiPgogICAgICA8cmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0iIgogICAgICAgICAgICB4bWxuczp0aWZmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3RpZmYvMS4wLyI+CiAgICAgICAgIDx0aWZmOk9yaWVudGF0aW9uPjE8L3RpZmY6T3JpZW50YXRpb24+CiAgICAgIDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPgogICA8L3JkZjpSREY+CjwveDp4bXBtZXRhPgpMwidZAAAse0lEQVR4Ae1dB3gU1RaeLUlIgFCl9/4A6RFBUIo+QDpWEB5KkyYoTQEJLQoIIlYQ6SBKEQSVjqgIgkDoEDok9BBqKEm2vP+/zKybzWxJsgmod75vdnbu3HLmv+fcU+6dGUWRm0RAIiARkAhIBCQCEgGJgERAIiARkAhIBCQCEgGJgERAIiARkAhIBCQC6UVg1KhRRtRhSG89srxE4B+HgCoc2n1JIdGQkEeJgCYcixYtemLx4sW5iYjdbpdC8pCwhvkhoeNfSQYFAZsNxxyDBg9eFXflSgSAmIg0E46WfyUoD9lN0+6V2wNC4MUXXxT4z5w5e6TBYAyNOnJkELRIYZBj0TTLAyJNNisReLAIQBCoJZSlS5fWGj/hA1v/N9+yFC5a1N6pU6fZKmXi+oOlUrYuNcgD4gFoDyubPh0dQ5PKYDQa7WazyX7s+PFXR48e3RiXrC+88IIUkgfUP1qzUkA0JDLxCPNJ+H6zZ8/tkpSY2MCKDX6IOTAg0HbrVryyY8eOCTg3LlmyhEIkHfZM7BvXpuQI5YpIBp/TMW/YsKHt8OHDeXZFRi5JSrJkh/ZQbt++bThyNMoYEhJiuXnzZpF9+/ff3Lljxx8gh8Jky2CyZPVuEJAaxA0wGZWsOeYbN20ajTYKIahrobbQ2qO1lZCQoEQdOhQ+b968YkiXDrsGzgM4OjrmAbT9r2uSjjnNpsXLltW5fu16HwoCNocWpy1FYcmSJYvl4qVLOVavXfseM8Ak40FuDwABKSCZBDpNK80xjzl9ZgI0hQLTir6Hw8ewq7TYbDYzNvuJ48c7hoeHN0GyTTrsmdRRLs0IZ9ElTZ5mAAKITFFTWGbNmtPjcuzl+nTMce7QHq5NQkDgsN8ywU+hw74RAkVTDAeDJkeuReR5BiAgNUgGgOpaJSf9sFu2bduW//LlS2OSkpIUcrprPudzaBFTUFCQ5ezZs1V79+49kNdQxK1AOZeV//2HgBQQ/2HptqZRow4KYdixc+cYDP/5kTGZY+62IDQMhengoUPDZ82aVYrlKGwe8stLfkZAgu1nQF2ruz9jDsd88eJ6N27c7JGYmMgsPmkCmlTUIleuXMm+dt2691kQAsKD3DIJASkgGQg0GVxzzKPPnv2AVpWrY+6teTrsRpPJdurUqZeGDRvWHPmlw+4NND9el066H8F0rUpzzL+aObNP3JW4Ot4cc9fy2nkAIlqYPFT27ttHh309BC1ROuwaOhl7lBokg/Clr4DdsnPnzoJXYq+MSvTBMXdHCh12zo3ExMRU6tWr12Dmkw67O7T8my4FxL94OmqDcAjHfOu27RFIzIsTXx1zRx0uf0wWi0U5dOjQ0GnTppXFNemwuwCUEadSQDIAVXUpu/WbJUsa3Lp5swsiUZy78Mkxd0eOw2GPi8v6888/S4fdHVB+TpcC4mdANcecx3PR0R+wephDfGrQ47yHL2TQYTfRYT99+vm3hw9vjTK2Bg0aSD/SF/DSmEeCm0bg3BXTHPOZM2f2s1isYXDM+eis33CGgCiYYVf27949HkK3FsJ3j8KHTc6wu+uUdKRLDZIO8FyLao75r7/+WvTylbhwznmAcf2KMYRBLGaMOXu2wuuvv/42aUAb6TLfXO9Dnv+FgF87769q/53/NMcc4dgI2FO5wbjpdczdAWmy2mwKnil5+9NPP62ATNJhd4dUOtOlgKQTQK24wzH/5pvG8fG3/0fHHJvfTCutHR5pUgUFBlrirl4N/u2338YzDcLJg9z8jIAUED8ASobljDmOprPnL3yAo3DM/VC12yqcHPbW77zzznPIKB12t2il/UKGjHBpJ+fvWVJzzGfMmDHAarHU8Ldj7g4VOuzxt28ru/fuHXfx4sU1BQoUuE1hxSYddnegpTJdapBUAuaaXXPMN27cWDz2Stxw1THPFKcZwmDMgsWM58+dKzt8+PB3SJt02F17KH3nUkDSh5/D9j9w6ND7YM4c2MWDTemsNjXFTXz26sjRo0M+++yzSigoHfbUoOclrxQQLwB5uqw65raFCxc2vXP7TofUOOb0U7jzjSZ4elA0Y8AbflIbFaZJxSXxcXFxgQgvT2BF0GrSxPLUcam4JgUkFWA5ZyVjqo55wLnz5ydwFIf28Pp6Hk0w6D8EBAQoSUmJyokTx/EurD+V+Ph4JSHhHusRu3N7nv7TYecjuidPnWoOh/0l5LXLGXZPiPl+TTrpvmOVLKeTYz7QarVVAZN6nDGnYJDxqS14pDDgcVrl+PFjyrVr14Q2uU0BuXdPyZo1q5Ite3YFmkFoGNSdrG29EwrcnTt3lMjIyPejoqJWVahQ4RaFGJvUJnqA+ZiW7vVBPrbzj8oGE4ZL2W2rNm4svXv7n3ugPbKREcmQrjfqLBhkdD7XcebMaaE1bkEgQoJDhCDgxXFK9JkzQqsgEqaQq4NDQpTsEBQsdVcoAKyLu7sNNFhAizksLGzCrJkz6bRzAJRviXcHmA/pmRJt8YGOv1WWX375hYJgD6sV9iWYuTqYlo55MizJyJp/wf94bBZL1Q/ytaLKhQsXlMDAQCU4S7DDlOKz5zdv3BCCwHLc8VpSJR7rru5Bq3Cj9mE6BEGcu/4g3YAl8QYI2+Nv9u+/ct26dRf4uiAskXcvVa6VyPNkCCTr1GRX5IkuAtAcZgiIdcGCBS3i4q5GgLFp/wgcKQjcNMHg8xuYn1D27t1D00e5eu2qEAqaTsyr5SfDOwuIczo1B/0bml80oXiNgsJ0HUExwK+xQkuZYaqVxFKUBRAOQZP8SRsCUkBSgRuYU7xXF8egtevXL7EkWfKhOJeyi2AHmZbMyzcm4uk/ZffuSGXfvn2CsfHOXQUvp04mGFrTrgKipWtHXhcmFkw0CgmFhWuxtPacBYW0gAbrjZs3y+JTCse3bNmyjw776dOnvTsyWoPy6EBAOukOKLz/0Rzz6dNnDLFZbZUwslvAnOBHwmjAC6jjhWDQ8b56FdoiOFgJDQ0VQuGLo+2JAjA+ZwEVMyJf/E9zDA9j3Xfos2VTguCnUHOxHdBkuHv3LmfY38Mjvz/WqlXrBsowWZpankDWuaZvzOpk/LcncWQGg9lg15fdsWPnHozgIRAMOxjScAPMegYONsO1FJKQkKxCk5CRuXvbyNjUDDHR0cJJ96UMaHEIHvNTGIVDjyM1CzYLzDZzrbCwyXNmzeKL56TD7q0jdK7LeRAdUPSStNE3KurI+MCgoBCcWy5fvmzg/MWatWuU/Qf2CZ8gNDSHYFCO5L4wul5bvqRpdWtmFh35S5cuCZ+HkTJoNzopytEjR96cNGlSTdRpke/39QXZ5HmkBkmOh+4ZZ8w5Kbho0dLnjh0/uvT8+fO2EydOGGNiomHWGDB6hwjhSKsZlRYNokcotQppoFPPScjQHDms0HKmSpUqrV++bNl/1TIiAqdXXqalREA66SkxSZaCkdpQuXJlOuIBeIz22982/5Zv//59Fsx4G+B4I2qk73gnq8TLCRnbOYrlJbvHy6xLNbHs0Cq2szExEGGldN++fQ8i+nZIhn09wpfiojSxUkCSPAEMJ5wIHJOyZcvaPW/evBuwB+DcCKGxwAnx7mQkrzLDz6CRrBAO+kbmatWqXatdu/bAJ554Yj0bxvdJZDQrFT0gTaxUgKVlHThkSKdDBw6Mgc1fgiYNJv3gs9vSrI39ZWKhHhvMKzsiaKYypUsrFStVmtWmTZtRXbp0iVFpl+aV1ok+HqUG8REoZht1/+Obhg8/+GD+2DFjqtWsWfMDhHETMe9hgoDYoFUeyOhMLQfh4EuucTCa8A3Ebe07dGiwcuXKrhQO0BlAUxG38NBpu1TA/0CySg2SBtghKIHYxWva8dKERzdv2RKBEG0rrqfi0nNUaVIZ0qfawdSpDvNqFcPfsPJDO3TMq1SpcqFGjRqjp0+f/qV63Qyfg1/LFbQiTQqJBpyPRykgPgIFhjevXftzjaZNG//JIj169AjYtWuXgj2J50Pffbfd/r1738c6q/JkVphdFigVnyZi0yIgEAwbnl60X79+3VSuXDkbhOPzDh06RLRr1+4y6YFgBGqCQSEuXLhwAq4dpeBS4zCP3LwjIE0s7xjRtOIkoeXWravFP/7k0x83bNhQDqN0EoWD2gRVGMdFRCz7YeXKao+FhY3IlStXPJjXDAGh6cNPrfltQ33kcEtsbCzfj2Vq0qTJxo4dOz6+dOnSfhQOCgYa48dCxRvgO3fuPPrgwYMjHn/88bN+I+JfVJHUIL53NgcT25RPPpmGpwdfz50n94g2rVp9xBclIJ3L383YhSkzf/78MqvWrBlz5vTp9nzug068GLbVNVuuTfqiQVCeS0ks0BhYbRKgYG7jJHyLkVOnTl2g1mdGmhHCIGjgxz+3b98++e69e2Wea9eubP/+/aMZ4oXg+FVgXe/ln3YuBcTHHnU2TSZO/HAXrPkaSDuSP1+BkZ07d1zEamh28UjtwiPWbjWJ3L17HF6qUD0RK3uDAgIsmFBhtCsZ7t4EhH4GAgEM2xohBIkwpyYPHDhwPNdYsS4wfoBmTqHtcps2bYo4euzYC1xN3LpVq3ZjxoxZzgWLmAeRz4awY1KxJeuoVJT7V2bVZtTXrFlTaVfk7m1g9mx4mzQd89WlS5Uc3rp1690EhmYXdo7U4l1Z/fr1e+NwVNRwPDeel9e5JB3mlyMs7E5AkM61XlaUMxcpUoRO+Ip69erhQ1PDxBr2Zs2aBa1evZrCaMOy+qzvhocPPhIVNehK3JWsfL49rFatz+fOndsX19mW1BwAIbWbFJBUIgbGpyllmTFrVt/Yy7GfYgY80WwOCLTbrZZcOXN/0rx5s4jixYtfY7XI54h2fffdd0UQdh114uTJrlwrpZldEAB8Ye3+47LaYkWWpTlFwciGlboVK1Y8BB/i3Y8++mg5r2ETmgpHoanwHPoLe7FyF8/Gl0V9YqlJiZIlD8786sfHChUy3HHWfqK0/PEZASkgPkPlyEjMuNumTPl4GWz8tjBlEqBNggLhG8BXOJs/3yMjX3vttVksQdPmkUcecYRaIyIi6kXu2TMOS0DqwWwS0S6UMWE1r4ECAsfbiqXqRgiRARrjVtWqVSfARPqwZMmSfKzQCHPKrJlTEJhqeN7jfXwOoRlXA6Ms5DUpIEdoDnvz5s/WgabZLv0O9kLaNykgacAOmkE8k75///78P61aHQmmLIRqaMIwfCqc6ABzwG/FihUZCgbdyiZUbcKJROEHvDVwYA841OGxly8XpgOO0LDl1MmTBgiGCRqI5tRCmFAj8I30kyyvmlMJ/L958+Zc+Cz08KNHj/bH+3nZno1aCJqCm6lO3brvfDl1Kl8BJJe4E7B0bFJA0ggeGF6YWnz0Njrm3A8Wi/iKlNAsqNJuMpkxWWhTcuTM8VX1qlVHwXc4z6ZUQRGRJoSL83zzzTcjYHb1jY6ONl2Ni6NgRNatW3fo+PHj1zE/Z8ERTqbgCcEaMGBAFwjmqAuXLhWFgyJMNfozNMmw/sqMhZUblixe/AzLQlgge3LOg1ikdZMCklbk7pcTzu8XX0z76Matm2/iJQtkYjE5CMYUjjh8DeaMzZM719ju3bt/wXSaPYpSCSHX+2HhCRMm1NoZGTky0GzeDIGbqDK1STWPhDDBNKu7c+eu989En3mKz344z9gjvw3mmhGm3NXXe/So8corr5yBIAotd59M+ZtWBKSApBU5lNNGaBwDPvxw8o6ExMSqjDrRzGG1KqPT9BJmFyJeu4oVKzoUz5as53WGhRGWdWgHpnGDYDhmweHcF/z+++9HHT9+ose169coGCnmVNCmDf6HsXGjRh2geb6RId37OPrjVwpIOlHUQr8rVq2qvn/3nu3gVS6Fh4z89Y4sjvBMgJ8gBCdb9mwLK1WrNuLp+vWFf6GaXUlgbBPmKigwQsjeeOONvgcOHhyOWfNHSCYjX6hf1KGRjbrFo7VVq1SZgVegdkc6r8uQrgZQOo9SQNIJIIuDwYU/MmPGrLcwBzEZy0zIoMkYmfnAzGR8I5xqStAtmF3joUUmI50RKgdjYxb8mT2IdJ2Jjq6JAIAwp1TBSNZf8DsY8TKVKlnyyJw5c2rly5cvXppWRNp/WzLA/Vftv7ImYmmfPGXKDwn3Elog9MuXyQl/xBkNCIOmIcz0T7DI63ChQkWGd+zYfjkiU6XWr18fAae9PedK9MwprS7WA+Ex8K0pzZo2rQeh2iJNKw0d/x2lgPgJy1HQDKNgSmHkL7x6zdrdkI9HICAM6+ouCCWDY7NCC4jXBt27e3f92rVrquB1pPlRxs7Qras55UwqyovXjD5Rt274tGnTxuKaDOk6A+Sn/7qd56e6/1XVUDhoauER13NFixR+/f67shyOegosIBwcnLjiF1MgVjsE45mz58/lZ3QKrorBk3AwpIuolblc2bK/qMLBgIH0O1KgnP4EKSDpx9BRAwSEYV4Tlp8vD80e+gW0AJ9b98i4uE7fw0ApCQoM4tqrFGaZowFmhCByvgMh3RstW7bsxmsMB1MjOeeT//2DgBQQ/+DoqAUMT7NK6d275wC8cecAtIEZzOtRSNTCJrxmzqvJCwGyc31W7cce6/fqq6+eQFkuPfGlfrUZeUgNAlJAUoOWD3k5kjP0i2NCmfLlu1KD0FzyxwhP0wqbqXSpUnMnTpw4D+RQ+4gZdh9Ik1nSgIAUkDSA5q0IXzJHf6Rty5Z/Fsifbxj8inT7CBAOhnTNWKd1YtCgQf1JA9qQZpW3zkjndSkg6QTQXfGRI0fS7DF069btg4DAgLUMVUGLpGm0p/ZJTEoy5ciRQ6n1+ONd+aAUQ7oQEGHOuaNBpqcfASkg6cdQtwYyNUwtgW/tsLAemO+4iox0wNPC1FaUV6pXqzZ2bHj4r6xHPh2oC7vfE6WA+B3SvyrUTC2s5I0uWLBAby30+1cO7/+0kC78jt8R0g1nCW+RMe+1yhy+IiAFxFek0pgPZpAI/eLtIotCs2efidlzYu6TqQUtJEK6eNVpfNu2bbuSBBnSTWNHpLGYFJA0ApeaYpoz3bt3r37QCFG+hn4Z0uUXb/FseX8I2FG0KUO6qQHeD3mlgPgBRG9V0JlWQ7938HKHbjCROCHoMfRL04qOOd6xu3Dy5Mmz0IbPmscbPfK67whIAfEdq3TlpD/CyNNzzz23JW+evOF4fiOFL6HNEjKky9nyksWLn+nTpw/fSqJAyNLVviycNgSkgKQNtzSVwvuqxIx3z549IjDLvgmT7MlCv5zUYPQLq3RN2TFbju+dd61fv/41GdJNE9x+KSQFxC8w+laJGvrl7LeCB5y6IXJ7E38pJM6hX67wVbDocTzeZrKR12VIl4g9mE0KSCbjroV+n3766ZMF8hfsw9AvXBJBhcloEqt0ixcrtu3LL78cxkQZ0s3kDnJpTgqICyCZcQp/gmFeY5cunRdky5Z9HkO/0CKJeLeVOU+ePHe4SpfaRoZ0M6M3PLchBcQzPhl2VXO627/8Yl+YVMfRUCA+8cbZ8gF4DPcgzmVIN8PQlxX/LRCAkIhnP9Zs2FB/0OAh9latWi1RCZcD19+iByWRmYGAEIaPP/64z7hx48qwQQiOFJDMQF628bdBwFkgtOmQvw3xklCJQGYgQCGRwpEZSMs2JAISAYmAREAiIBGQCEgEJAISAYmAREAiIBGQCEgEJAISAYmAREAiIBGQCEgEJAISAYmAREAiIBGQCEgEJAL+R0A8/un/ajO/Rjx5h2eMDEb1G3+ZT4BsUSLwECPgvMjP+f9DTLIkTSKQOQgIgfj6669zYS+lNimFJHOw/8e3Ip5o+5vfJZeJW3fv3t3/4sWLL8LUqgxTi59dpsklPw/wN+/cB02+84M6D5qWdLWPF63lxJdhc6OSwHRVJAtLBJwQ+McICLSFBa/QScK9Sa3h1MHyb/oQ+McICGCg3yF9j/TxgyztgsA/SUBcbk2eSgTSj8BDJyDyjR7p71RZg/8QeBgFxPk9tf67U1mTRCANCDxUAsLQ7LJly8qtWrUqKA33IotIBPyOwEMhIJpZ9f3335eaO3fu3kOHDjXinfLdtH6/Y1mhRCAVCDwUAqLRCw0SnJCQkMVqtWbV0uRRIvAgEXioBAQvcbaps9/SD3mQXCHbdiCQJgGhSaSaPyYeNRPJUWsq/tDvqFixopi/wHf7SI8BR3FeqVIlA68zLRVVOmc1aLSml07nSrX/pE0Hh7TSqlWrW17FQcvj89ENjT6Xz+yMeveZ2j7U7pl9w12vzgy5L1UQ3AmVJjRpbnvFihXln332Wfv48eNbp6IS4ae88cYbH7Zr1+4swBAOPmh1t87MqN5HKppInlUt79Y/UoUmeaE0nGkdjaK6QuOpygykkbSkhp7U5nfcloqjXlvawOTIyz+qILjrlwwXFEfDP/zwQ+HXXnutUd++fV/o0qXLf2fPnl3CiVJjaiQWeUOvX7+eC8eg1atXh+HLS7ZPP/20A86NTL927VpO/neq3/Wvq4Bkcc7w0Ucf/adjx47PvPrqqw2w2re40zXH/Tilef3rzPxnzpzJ1bt373rYn+/evXuLSZMmVXSqQGgvp3Ovf3mf2IVgO7fDgkjP5rWCvzI47m3nzp15u/XqVR8DyPPdunV7dsqUKeX/yqZoGtopya9/9ZjbYwO4T20tneMepk2bVhafwW7MfcaMGeIN+GoljjzOg15sbGz2/v371+7UqVMT3PfjJ06cyKE16pxPS/N09OUGtBHANnXq1Or4EGUEFgU2RaX8KpL4fBhuSsH3vH977LHHRrzzzju/sUGk4bL+alp2/pIlS6xDhw7tfvDgwU+RPZ6ZExMTzRCK0GzZst1GfQn8Tjgc9uz46tJP8+bNa4d8pMV1rRVBslKDnDt3rv13331XElUlDBsx4sUDe/eOxgcxK+C6oJPH0NDQtc8888xbYOjDOBVlme7jJvKvWbOm4MKFC8egIyjIIWjPUX9AQMDhcuXKvffhhx9+zTrZIdg9+lQaHriH0RgQKi5YsOAFlkXdQQMGDOh55MiRzlhnVrlAgQIDpk+f/pmWn3l0NkEjcCi+fPnyMVeuXHkRebI404gvWu2tUqVKBLalLO8DjQ7cu3btuhi+4oqvvvrqa090aNfefPPN5levXu358ssvPw/rIAHNOepi29y0vMOHD28dHR09ol69eo1ff/31G6Drv3v37h2Hhag1mI98xi04OHhb7dq1B4LXtuKUlouB/ITrWTAIjDp//nxPpOdgft43tltFihSZCuxG4DzRh/tlGbF5Gpm1PGzBBonsDdAjIRw1ypYtOwz+wWMgsjz8hxrY3wAjFlq7du2v0CrvsyAIAX3Cf9DqcRzxzXDBMI888sg2MNO48uXLT8FxYoUKFWYHmM1KmTJlVuD/eLQzBdcmFC1aVDCbowKdPyoD0MlPwHcAP4rcsWNRrly5dj766KOtCxYsWA11hoHmfqC/Cto/BM3yNKrhV2fJUL5sgvHwDY+noSlOQBi7FCtW7IuqVas+RRxA/6OVK1d+BZ93jo2MjFyA0et73H8wOsPGDvHUADpXXIbAVb58+fLjPMH3Qiq3aNXq4P4DB6YYTSY77uGL4sWL/85ruA/XQYLJ3ASN7777bgt84/DUhQsXXixVqtQUYFCPNP7nP/+BXFR5FcJ2d+vWrUs6de68gH3kC42sHINjFjBfawhxTZ6DbsF9/O+64V7ENeSvhMcQWpw8eVJoQLTnmpX3I/KiTMmYmJia+MKWpXfvvsNB41oMlCeB8fNg8OolSpSogXt5DQNnjnXr1m0ZOHBgJ1Rmo3Bs3LixMEzs3WjnbfDLfORrhIG1Cso2RNk5J44fH9K2bdut27ZtC/X1flMQqpMgmKdfv3598DliO8yUGbhBYQLo5FVwY2MaNWpkh8kxSb3uiTFSgHvs2LEizZo1s3/++ef/1avfTZqgEYI5Bd8gPzhixIixTZs2vQ0zrZZeftKPbwBugimXBEEpxjzeGJgjHPPBN3qyYcOGdpTfCmYpwDS97e233375yaeesr/yyiub0J64T+2olx9pon4I1Te4/z9QdxngaMF9nJw8eXJ9lzIpcON1jcaxY8c2JY0vvfTSzzQBXco6Tqm98Xlpe/v27Zc7Et37FqJNTuDi3i9hAHpPLeOWF/jpauaB5ujXtFmzO1/ggTae6+Gg5e3Zs2df3P+lt956K7xx48YJHIxYRm/r0KHDLPShHXnCeL1169aHUU88zDFnM9dRFBqvJvsE9/uTmqiLo6OA+sctA6uAW8lomLj7DCPwrDlz5vDjkhbeEK+TsbhrNwgVFo6RP/zw4cMDw8PD26INm9Zxrg3jHFgJ5jFBsAJ4HQ89CRBv3LgRynOUpT3qU5QMavc2RsyKsLnfggnVGObKTpQNYPvaznZI/8yZM1uaTKYEBAXGsR3cg1uwSCNHKNqxm375ZRlGtD3wweqCCS9q9Ws4qPdqmjBhwrdP1q/f7OzZsw3QpmAmtOsWa9LADW1xyX4BCMVqmEFR8MkqwMTajEtaAIR0phiC2T5p/Omnnwr8/vvvyzFybl20aFEjaJxrNWvWFBhoNKp9ZQRjfQUhbI/RvQ0GwKFsH5svNFKY3eIlanH6sRuNNCVMDifA6ZrrX5huSTCz8+3Zs2c0BuT2EOINyOPoQ96DxiswcbsAo6MHDhyIAEYjwTMVmjdv3hhCdghlAtkXzK/2SSBM6l2NGjZ8Dhr6WZhyLZFHfCTVlQZfzwmAAOH555/fBKk+j5sUIwJGXTHauVZEYrQybdq02d6iRYtorYyW7lpGO1fLKphJr0gNAgajv+EYFbV8bo6CnmHDho2qVauWHbbrJ2o+IXSuZcgwTAOQw5s0aWLF/QhNoNHgmh/non4APB6jmn3+/PnCydU6Sic/cRNtIJDxMUc5DCylmc9bGwh4fAlTyA4Bj0dAoRTLeGiHl7VN0Ij2viCNMIWL8ALa0x3h0S+kUVxDAGPO0ygDk6WQWkZPSAQvUIOgX69AgwgzWquD5Vw3bdB8qUOH/k2aNk3A/XjVINAcXeF/UPutUevjfYm2nevXMMEg/ELjxk/bad3873//m6nmSdHv6v2KemCGHUb9mhbRu1fnpvRHDADLyuzQHo/CZm9QunTpCI68GJWDoE3s7GjXnbUiTRAXFhY2CjPiReFENWc6pNgrIcxnsVhSgMF0Xzb4QKaQkBAFdup85kebuo4xbHKRDjv1J4xYxl27dgkVjWBBirZVYOn8BcM27l64cOGFMIOOwGYOLFSokNUVA/WcNr0Y5aH2J6EJ5Y/t27uSJqSnaIPp2oa89KEU+DOfwTw7ifQAaGU+BOZ202j88ccfc8He7woav4CpeRb3T+0r/B+VLkefjR492gAfRdCCQWKcATRCA3VmI8zrtrEMvgDtYWAf5suX7zs2BSEjjSk0JmjnZ7SVatWq/YrLV/m/evXqM3jU63dgyjrEIAIL4Pvbt2/XhX8TjDTygsc+0R1hNGaBw9OUgtGhQ69vP/vsMwUCwyiEpy2RF6HCVkMTxMHkaYHTFQDfUxm/XAO4QYhQ3YTdfgyqWYFmEMzmWrmWjlHk/B9//HEbplY51zzaOUZKMosVgh4GHHLDZJnOa8AnEbuWTe8ohBCaNAb7upjoaM7rDMMu0vUKMA0DhAkdqOTPn1/4Bexsb9hpNGLgqgMaA+GIz2JdKJfopayghQKPdrbdunWLgxlNTgYudBkT6aneBFf6WArCju4wKdCie8BrFBAbXuOUojTuU6TB6Y6Ddr6MwMhd4LwbGoj3rYsxBJ/Cr6D+I+CVnDDF86CSs0hzDGgpGkKCroBoEYjTp09XxqgWd+3a6cIgpCQqTyHNzpUiJCsoxyiWiJEvGh1eWb3uV9Cd29T+I7IRAJs0FqPKDS3N0xF2eiKFH2CFuMsHsMX9IPRcAfmU3Llzh2C1ceX4+HiGTXU7QquLzA4crn/77bexGChqwx/Jg2hKHEd8bLo4oo0sEJDriPcfhfngVsi1NnjU+grh0SrAwArtEwozsCr6zYxz3Xa08nfv3jUhynMDju150PgkR9W6devexfX7HKhlTMcxAZpd1XJeawG9RuwKwvz075SRI0fSWnFbDjhaW7duY8yTJ2dUyZIl7yGjW7oxoAksUDf7nW1Qw3rddAVEe/kaiA0EM+SH9tiDSlOjeu0YkQwwzTZ7pcC/GbS1XF5rzZkzp4iosEM8bALUHNjATArC2D+A8XweFNkRwE+BMMbCGfbaIchPZrpG55o0sbyvG8yGYMwXmDBXtSEoKIgTjj4Vhd9nv3PnjgG3GIPgii4/pKjI6J0VtJHfZDBkJeOnqEMnQRUkC/J7s1QcpYGRGYNRrJogNL7jooc/GMx9AsgdIFrPJCE6FAeb9iUwvNcO1ugBE1FXmgF6FDQPk1mfTwQxcxo3cnowQA4EaMLU81YP8iHI4r3voEHiocYVOJCdIVgX4V8F8R691c882MzQChcQQLjA/GzTXTlc4zo0joTcUoUZbPcE0GiDqfEyBOUGqvJJkLW+glBFd+3a9db9pr30ledBRa3ifh2gq8AlzIng6Pa+tQLq0UABd0lze4r75EDnU387VwKfVeNx5+QU/3UFBDapnfZriRIlojCL+wKA2wZCbqco7VtCqjratyr1cwEoAuszuPdrca9BgANtWiUkNPQIOk3BLPkxzLf8qd/6g0nFZKtgPJhzhxCKNiJMfAhhT48OUlophWZjWxxUUkSKdOoUwIJvSlgtFiu1lE4evSQ7NIKvwiTKo999rVuvPY9pugLCmVoyBiI9a6F23wPgXK4wm1EsmAoigqBXK8shkmJyiryQWd1zoF4l6UhDZ4gOTEcVyYpqDv2IoUN3Iqp0C1j0QIY/EYAIgg3rEQfkY9RIy5NhOGh9hXmqLZhgtCPw8CraHuwLjc59BVpJr8e+QluJCG5cgq9XAm1wc5dfDIpYJpIVAZNHIbT3wPS+DlypZna13+9T5OdfXQEBUEKCBw0atAuRgh2Y4WYEZjajWJ6ABIBmCgcXCMIMyaWulRFg+ZnuTKlOBd4EH+ImVhHMgyPcB37IaIRGY4CDGbsmAMnogeYxIbpkgUOfb//+/TXhcK9BXcny+OsENJBJ2V4sIlILEI7uv3379vGIBMV5otGprwoilF8RDvFGDzSRH2iyWcHsW7G2qi1GbU66JnH0VnFyFEe7nKSzYN6kzs0bN4sGBWe5ArMvYwBwtJoxf3QFBE2JWUZoESsWIA7ZsGHDpl69ek2EAziYHULgkccxejAsjLwcgZIQPssxZMiQ7VDHdNAZOvzbCghoV3BPIpICpo/ASthuGADmIbkh0i2csOJ8CPNpG2bZyaxi7gILLL+DT1Ee1wpi53xKCmbSyqXnqNGIZSAjQV8nrOOag/paeqIR1wSN0DqctefKhVIqDbr9pZmbEKz5P//8c3dMzL6M/PNxQ4GsixEnlicf4P4Fb0CDDAjKEsTQqgUDZoYJSKabWOqNsuNNUJG/9OjZMxxT+mP69OmThHVSwwg887hsVoQ0SyP/OtjqIU8++eRALINXkFfsLnl1TzE6CRPJFwdYpwJRViddNwmON9OJrehY3UxIBP1iuQyWMVzkzO2vv/66EsyyAuZXezDHHZ1yfC9wdqxAWBgXF1cPOLRBPiu1Co86+Z2TGIVzDDzOFzz9J424TsE8hTmoDjCzFmJm+Vs8398J9elNNNpOnTqVc/Dgwd9fv3Gjap06dZ5ZunQp79WtmcXBEm0YIBibsQ7qB7QxFxpyO2amj6Icy2okinuESfo+ln+UrlGjxkgIyiD0qdf7Aq3sC6/5tIZ4JF6pwUxtg/6kx37X2qAm8LSRWMP0adPGYhmxMSoqahRGqZZYtToJk3Kb0chNrOykPV4W157H6NUHkZQriKTUwbKHKJR1C7heowwHYjfAXvVGV4riKBeAckGkN8VFnQR0mBH5s+CSV4dTZQ7TmDFjfsBiyJe2bNmyiGYWVji/Dz9tNeYvYoGDKW/evEUwd/Qsrg1E3aFYAvEKyqxAG2KtlA4ZyZIQesyCcm7nZZJlTnlCxjS+995732CVa+C+ffvmwA95CmbyOMzfrMO1OISczVjhXAzOfEssnRkIZslSv169NhjUNrAsmNwjc+K6mFSD8L+G9WzbYXJHDXr77V6lS5RYjlUD8VhDZcZAWgZr6kYAjzYwSyssWrLkKfRNdvCFV4ZkHwID9qOv/oqCaFRwQICZ/e5x0+aLWD/aUdBnPkX5vDEiBkNhFhjwoMpoLHDbAvt2HJZzzyE1UJ2JbBC8Rqa8XrJkyUmI8ryHaX8Oz8JmZT5fN6j6OxC864gY+TTZ51wvOuACyp5Bp2thUufLKf4jL9s6FRwceD7FRf0EMqAJq2UXQzPugy8yEU77JET5JqFNjtLsVBPAT8RSiWXQHCNhgh1V0z0yHvKIDYx8HOW9draWX+fIdox4FmUuJv/2YAn4BAjKx+gfBXsi+pL9zUHoHmbrv8XoPwoh/DNMw+6VRgoQdiPKxeGZmMcwITljb2TktP179kwFHpfBC8Fg2FD0xR4MktWh0Y507dq1AR4cOg+sRSgWWKGp5JsWicO0wCVigHr0NHPyQupZ7tx5jkLx8B48blobCNPH5sydm/njWcDrZKTHWv+6yLviLkCEsFSG7VoFApIHknirYsUqJ0aMGLoLNy9ujOaEOur+VYOP/7CmqBQeDIrBvIGeaeC2FgQSgmCiBUNIKZyk1euIRTMDoWw+rKVnMrpryyH4eCCpBHyO6sCgMEa9BGiTM1hOvRtmhTZx5cjrrjLndDAw89MUE8zkfC2V/x3tgsbSK1eurA7GLQDGuwff8DSc+Uj4EmINE9vDLswiX9ugkFBYmB9+WRVojAYQiqKYTL2GtW6/49pval0G+KTB0CZ5sQAz2lv9vH9o4OxqH3rLLvoYq3OzgfmTgJlPk4tow4g2Qn1swxsNya+T8ZFCwtxtPi8rcFeBH9I90eeH6oVfwhGXu7uNDOTpurtyfktX2/dEg0+PEbgjyFv9mXT/Gd7X7u7fYzpvvsH9B2LMPFJwIJl+ITY9wKaWhtTmdwWFtKqDBk0Xf+HgFxw1Wp1p9HdfsQ21v3j/HDwFBkx32ui3eBJUp6z3oybJErycqH2YKszS2+9eSJKXJQISAYmAREAiIBGQCEgEJAISAYmAREAiIBGQCEgEJAISAYmAREAiIBGQCEgEJAISAYmAREAiIBGQCEgEJAISAYmARMAFgf8D5p7OVH6ybdwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
            <h3 id="message"></h3>
            <form action=${this.getBaseURL() + suffix} id="captcha" method="post">
                <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeK070UAAAAAHuzSEGgoqbuLGuJq-GRDd-LA4kH" data-callback="onSubmit" hidden>fill captcha</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
`;
    }
}

web3.tokens.dataChanged = (oldTokens, updatedTokens) => {
    const currentTokenInstance = web3.tokens.data.currentInstance;
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = new Token(currentTokenInstance).render();
};
]]></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```